# Cancel downloading symbols in Debug Help Library

Tags: winapi, dbghelp

Debug Help Library allows to load symbols from external storages. You just call [SymSetSearchPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symsetsearchpath), specifying symbol servers, and then [SymLoadModuleExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symloadmoduleexw) loads symbols from the specified locations.

Downloading symbols may take some time and I am currently looking for a way to cancel downloading symbols. But suddenly I couldn't find any API for that.

Is there a way to cancel downloading symbols?

Comment: I doubt there is. The best you can do is offload symbol loading onto a sacrificial thread of execution that you're willing to give up on. Since [*"All DbgHelp functions, such as this one, are single threaded"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symloadmoduleexw#remarks) I cannot envision how cancellation of an operation could possibly be implemented or exposed in the API.

Comment: @IInspectable, I've expected it, but still hoped that I have a chance. I am currently using a separate process that downloads symbols and just terminate it when the downloading has cancelled. But I don't like this solution and it looks a bit dirty.

Comment: Terminating a [sacrificial process](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090212-00/?p=19173) is far less dirty than [terminating a thread](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811). Sometimes you're going to have to make compromises in aesthetics, when you're dealing with a design that wasn't actually designed.

Comment: You cannot cancel loading modules, nor can VisualStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can althrough only at a specific times you have no control over.

To cancel the download you:

1. Register for the callback funcation with [SymRegisterCallback64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symregistercallback64) or [SymRegisterCallbackW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symregistercallbackw64) funcation.
2. In the [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nc-dbghelp-psymbol_registered_callback64) handle the CBA_DEFERRED_SYMBOL_LOAD_CANCEL message.

e.g.

```
    SymRegisterCallbackW64(process, sym_register_callback_proc64, nullptr);

    BOOL CALLBACK sym_register_callback_proc64(__in HANDLE h_process, __in ULONG const action_code, __in_opt ULONG64 const callback_data, __in_opt ULONG64 const user_context)
    {
        switch (action_code)
        {
...
        case CBA_DEFERRED_SYMBOL_LOAD_CANCEL:
            if(<test for cancel now?>)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            break;
...
        }

        // Return false to any ActionCode we don't handle
        // or we could generate some undesirable behavior.
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: I see. It is so sad that they didn't add a way to notify about progress where an application could also cancel downloading symbols.

Comment: If you look at the CBA_XML_LOG callback event, it gives you a XML blob that you can break down to get the what is downloading and the percent progress of the download.

Comment: wow, I've never heard about CBA_XML_LOG! Really, thank you so much. I need to update progress bar while symbols are loading. So CBA_XML_LOG is what I need.